# How to join the tables in linq to sql?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

```
Table1 :
    userid name       address
    1      venkat      srinagr
    2      venkatesh  sainagar

Table2:
id userid lat     lon
1   1     14.000  15.000
2   2     14.3526 15.3698
```

by passing "venkat" as parameter then need to pull all matching records and his userid,name,lat,lon.
in above table1 "venkat" contains in both rows then need to pull 2 records.how to get userid,name,lat,lon for all matching rows..
for sigle record i am able to get.but there are multiple rows how to get please tell me....

Comment: Try this:
`var q = from u in Table1 join ll in Table2 on u.userid equals ll.userid select new { userid = u.userid, name = u.name, lat = ll.lat, lon = ll.lon };`

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var result = from p in cxt.Table2

                                 where p.Table1.Name.Contains(name) 

                                 select new

                                 {
                                    p.Users.User_Id,p.Users.Name,p.Latitude,p.Longitude

                                 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Im sure someone will say this is not the most effective way but this is how i would do it.

```
string InputString = "venkat";

var tab =(from a in db.tablea
          from b in db.tableb
          where a.userid == b.userid && a.name == InputString
          select new
          {
              UserID = a.userid,
              Username = a.name,
              Latitude = b.lat,
              Longditude = b.lon
          }).FirstOrDefault();
```

FirstOrDefault() is only if you want to force only one output or null,
if you want a collection of some sort, then just remove it.